# WPF Xaml converter Error

Tags: wpf

I am getting a compilation error as

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Converters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    G:\C#\Practice\DataGrid\DataGrid\obj\x86\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs  12  7   DataGrid

Below is my Xaml code, I am new to WPF please help me out. I have the converter Class.

```
<Window  x:Class="DataGrid.MainWindow "
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="500" Width="700"
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Converters">
<Window.Resources>
   <c:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BoolToStringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="59*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="402*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,55,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Courses}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="datagrid1" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" Height="339" Width="610">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="DataGridCheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Course Title" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Course Description" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Descrption}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Required" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsRequired, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,539,32">
        <TextBlock Text="Select Enroolment:" FontSize="15" 
                   Height="26"
                   Grid.RowSpan="1"
                   Width="134">
        </TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Text="Select Course:" 
               Width="139" FontSize="15" 
               Margin="0,32,0,0">
               </TextBlock>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Margin="0,0,69,33"
              Name="comboBox1"
              Width="476"
              Height="23"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did namespace `Converters` lies in the same assembly as that of MainWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Converters"`

You should check the namespace of your Converters class, that is what you should put in place of `Converters`. If `Converters` is your class, then you should put whatever it says after namespace in your `.cs` file.

Example:

```
 namepsace MyNamespace {
      public class Converters { }
 }
```

Then your XAML would be:

```
 xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

Extra:
If you want to be more specific, you can add the assembly parameter as well.

```
 xmlns:window="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyNamespace"
```

Where Assembly can be found in your Build Properties (Right-click Project, Properties, Application, Assembly Information)

Your default namespace can also be found in the Build Properties as well.

Comment: @KCS Added some info about where to locate it in the project itself instead of just the `.cs` file.

Comment: thanks again, i have added the cnverter as .cs file as i am doing small POC.

Comment: #Bob I'll bump ya since the OP isn't accepting the answer which is a good answer.

Comment: @MichaelEakins Thanks! Just want him to remember to answer questions that help him, that might help others with the same problem. :)